# Center li elements with ul

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have `li` elements in a `nav` menu, and I want to center the elements in the `ul`. I know this question has been asked many times, but I have tried almost everything and still cannot get it to work the way I would like. Here's the relevant portion of the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav"id="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="HomePage.html" id="homepageLink">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Login.html" id="loginLink">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="Registration.html" id="registrationLink">Registration</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[Here's the HTML for the whole homepage](http://pastebin.com/PNyz8L0e)

Comment: add you complete code,where is your css part?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tXzGeNGG

Comment: add some code of what you've been trying

Comment: create a snippet / fiddle so that it may be easy for everyone to understand the question...

Comment: I just want to center the li elements.

Comment: You have a closing `</ul>` tag too much.

Answer (score 1):

add this css code

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: With pleasure but i have 11 reputation